# Using Oneway keyword in AIDL Interface

Tags: java, android, aidl

I am developing an Android App on Android Studio on my MacBook. I need to declare an asynchronous interface. Look below

```
  import com.goel.test.data.ITestDataCallBack;
  oneway interface ITestService {

  void getTestData( in android.os.Bundle data , in 
       ITestDataCallBack callback );
   }
```

However, this throws the following compilation error
 or AidlTokenType.Import expected, got 'oneway'. This issue can be resolved if I move it to the method level and the same result happens. However, this is not suitable for me because the android documentation says I can declare it at the interface level. I have tried the other suggestions on StackOverflow related to this problem but nothing has worked. Please let me know if you have a solution and don't just tell me to move it to method level that is not an option even though it produces the same result.

Comment: it compiles just fine, if you have any compilation errors post them as a whole gradle output

Comment: hi, it does compile fine actually you are right. Sir how do i do this suggestion to remove the red line oneway keyword                 "please do un-inject Language/Reference from suggestion that may help you, i had same issue in few hour ago, now worked perfectly."

Comment: if it compiles just fine, then simply ignore any "red line"